# (C++) error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, string, googletest

I'm trying to write a function that would return a substring from the given start and end indices. This is the code that I've written but when i run it it gives me error. I'm using gtest to run it not main().

```
template <typename S>
S substring(S string_, int Istart, int Iend)
{
    S substr = string_[Istart];
    for(int i=(Istart+1); i<Iend; i++)
    {
        substr += string_[i];
    }
    return substr;    
}
```

**And this is the error i get:**

```
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
lab2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘S substring(S, int, int) [with S = const char*]’:
test.cpp:56:1:   required from here
lab2.cpp:91:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
     S substr = string_[Istart];
                ~~~~~~~^
```

My test code is this:

```
TEST(subStr, T1){
string str="he";
EXPECT_EQ(str,substring("hello", 0, 2));
}
TEST(subStr, T2){
string str="urge";
EXPECT_EQ(str,substring("hamburger", 4, 8));
}
```

Comment: you're trying to convert a char to a string. string_[Istart] is a char. Try += rather than =

Comment: The message is nothing if not self explanatory. In your calling context `S` is `const char *`, and thus `string_[Istart]` is `char`. Assigning `char` to `const char*` is invalid.

Comment: How should i fix this?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes i understand this, I just can't seem to fix it. Kindly help

Comment: `substring("hello", 0, 2)` This will use the `substring<const char *>` instantiation. If you meant to use `substring<string>` instead, then pass a `string` as argument, or specify the instantiation explicitly.

Comment: `EXPECT_EQ(str,substring(string("hello"), 0, 2));` would probably do it, but even then I doubt it. you're still assigning `char` to `string`.

Comment: @WhozCraig no it's still giving me error. This is the new error:   

 error: conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type {aka char}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ requested
     S substr = string_[Istart];

Comment: That would be the second part of that comment. As I said, it will solve the conversion problem, but introduce another (initializing `string` from `char`, which has no defined initializer).

Comment: @MahreenAthar Replace `S substr = string_[Istart];` with `S substr; substr = string_[Istart];`.

Comment: @dxiv yes thank you! it worked!

Comment: What's wrong with simply using [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)?

Comment: @MahreenAthar As a matter of general practice, you should not rush to accepting answers before you make sure that they do in fact solve your problem.

Comment: @dxiv You're right. I'll keep this in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the intended type is `string`. A `+=` operator exists for the `string` type.

A simple fix is to replace

```
S substr = string_[Istart];
```

with

```
S substr;
substr += string_[Istart];
```

**which will not work for `const char*` types as pointed out**

The following works for both `string` and `const char*`.

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename S>
S substring(S string_, int Istart, int Iend)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<S, std::string>) {
        if(Istart < Iend){
            return string_.substr(Istart, Iend-Istart);
        }
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<S, const char*>) 
    {
        if(Istart < Iend){
            std::string temp = std::string(string_);
            return (temp.substr(Istart, Iend-Istart)).c_str();
        }
    } 
    else throw;
}
```

Comment: This will badly fail when `S` is a `const char *`, as happens in OP's question.

Comment: I'm only assuming that a `+=` operator exists for `S`

Comment: Oh, it exists, but in a wrong context per the OPs posted usage. If `S` is `const char*`, what do you think `substr += string_[Istart];` will do? *not compile* ? It *will* compile (though it should at least spew a warning about an uninitialized `substr`usage).

Comment: @rohitt The semantics of `+=` is completely different from the `=` assignment that the OP intended. With the first example from the question `substring("hello", 0, 2)`, the type `S` is a `const char *`, the variable `S substr;` defines an uninitialized pointer, then `substr += string_[Istart];` adds `string_[0] = 'h' = 104` to that uninitialized pointer. That makes no sense, and certainly does not implement the `substr` OP wanted. I suggest you actually try the code before proposing it as an answer.

Comment: @rohitt The new "*more robust form of the code*" fails just the same with `substring<const char *>`, for the exact same reasons as before. See for yourself [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dfWrc7).

Comment: thanks, I've specified that it works with `string`, so to avoid any confusion. I've added a check on the indices.

Comment: @rohitt In that case the it's no longer about the template function `template <typename S> S substring`, but instead about the specialization `string substr<string>`.

Comment: Apparently, I can't delete an accepted answer :(  Although curious as to why was it accepted if it shouldn't work? please edit the answer if possible.

Comment: @rohitt It works because the OP never removed my original recommendation of passing `string("hello")` (i.e. construct a `std:string` from the input argument at the *caller* site rather than sending `const char*` as-is). Doing both (that caller-side conversion *and* your code  which eliminates the broken initializer in that context) completely changes the guts of that function.

Comment: makes sense, I'll delete it as soon as the OP *rejects* the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With the given calling context, this:

```
EXPECT_EQ(str,substring("hello", 0, 2));
```

utilizes an expansion of

```
substring<const char*>
```

and therefore the resulting code becomes:

```
const char* substring(const char* string_, int Istart, int Iend)
{
    const char* substr = string_[Istart];
    for(int i=(Istart+1); i<Iend; i++)
    {
        substr += string_[i];
    }
    return substr;    
}
```

Clearly that's not going to work. `const char* substr = string_[Istart];` is initializing `const char *` from `char`. As I see it you have two choices, but only one of them remotely realistic. Since `EXPECT_EQ` tests equivalence, going the pointer route will not work *no matter what*. You need to have a comparable `std::string` *guaranteed* on at least one side of that test, and the only way to guarantee that whilst still affording your expressive arguments is like this:

```
template<class S>
std::string substring(S s, int Istart, int Iend)
{
    return std::string(s).substr(Istart, Iend - Istart);
}
```

This will take anything compatible to `std::string` as a source argument. The result is ALWAYS a `std::string`, which can then be used in comparison against a variety of things, including `char[N]`, `const char *`, and of course, `std::string`.

It still has a huge caveat, that being `Istart` and `Iend` must be ordered. Eliminating that frailty is the very reason the standard library `substr` member of `std::string` doesn't take a begin,end; it takes a begin,length. Nonetheless, this is easily the simplest way to do what you want.(the single-line nature calling out the very usefulness of such a thing notwithstanding).

**Example**

I don't have GoogleTest, but a simple assert macro will demonstrate testing against different comparisons to `std::string` will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template<class S>
std::string substring(S s, int Istart, int Iend)
{
    return std::string(s).substr(Istart, Iend - Istart);
}


int main()
{
    const char *kvalptr = "welcome";
    std::string kvalstr = kvalptr;

    auto res = substring("abdwelcomedef", 3, 10);

    // test that both lhs prospects test against our result
    assert(kvalptr == res);
    assert(kvalstr == res);

    // output res and one of the prospects.
    std::cout << res << '\n' << kvalptr << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
welcome
welcome
```

Comment: When you construct a string anyway, wouldn't it make sense to drop the template and take a first parameter of type `std::string`? Or in other words: Is there any use in keeping the template, except to stay as close as possible to the original code?

Comment: @churill absolutely, I concur. I think the OP is confused enough. Adding in implicit conversion in the arg list would remove what I highly suspect is a requirement of whatever the OP is tasked with; namely a template "thing". But certainly I would dump the template, use `std::string s` as the first argument, and just return `s.substr(...)`, calling out even moreso just how pointless such a template is in the first place.